# Prove if the polyhedron $A x \leq b$ is bounded, then the cone hull of all rows of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls, convex-cone

Let $ P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d:Ax \leq b\}$ be a polyhedron, where $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1^T\\a_2^T\\...\end{bmatrix}$, then the cone hull of $(a_1,a_2,\cdots)$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$. How to prove this statement?

I think the intuition is pretty clear, but I don't know how to express them in math notations and give a strict proof.

My idea:

- if the polyhedron is not bounded, then it has at least one recession directions

$$ \text{rec} P = \{Ax\leq 0\} \neq \varnothing$$

- For nonzero $y \in \text{rec}P$, there should be $-y\notin \text{cone} (a_1,a_2,\cdots)$

Could someone help me?

Comment: Why put the (why?)s next to your ideas? Are you testing to see whether we can follow your logic? Or are these hints copied from your assignment? I don't mind which it is, but you should be transparent about it.

Comment: @TheoBendit Because I think my if-then statements still needs further proofs but I cannot find one, although they are intuitive.. Sorry for the misleading notation, I've edited the question.

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C= \{ \sum_k \lambda_k A^T e_k \}_{\lambda \ge 0}$. Note that $C$ is a closed, convex cone.

Suppose $C$ is strictly contained in $\mathbb{R}^d$. In particular, there is some point $y \notin C$.

Hahn Banach shows that there some $h \neq 0$ such that $h^Ty > 0$ and $h^ T (A^T \sum_k \lambda_k e_k) \le 0$ for all $\lambda_k \ge 0$ ($y$ plays no role other than to establish $h \neq 0$). Equivalently,
$\lambda^T Ah \le 0$ for all $\lambda \ge 0$, or $Ah \le 0$.

Now note that if $y \in P$, then $x+t h \in P$ for all $t \ge 0$, and so $P$ is unbounded.

Comment: I'm new to convex analysis, although read many times, I still cannot understand your proof..:( Could you please expand your answer a little? Thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: For example, what's the name of Hahn Banach's statement you mentioned, where can I find further information?

Comment: The Hahn Banach theorems are fundamental tools in convex analysis. The geometric form can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems) for example.